# Why does pycharm warn about "Redeclared variable defined above without usage"?

Tags: python, pycharm

Why does PyCharm warn me about `Redeclared 'do_once' defined above without usage` in the below code? (warning is at line 3)

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.'+filetype)):
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        do_once = 0
        for line in file:
            if 'this_text' in line:
                if do_once == 0:
                    //do stuff
                    do_once = 1
                //some other stuff because of 'this text'
            elif 'that_text' in line and do_once == 0:
                //do stuff
                do_once = 1
```

Since I want it to do it once for each file it seems appropriate to have it every time it opens a new file and it does work just like I want it to but since I have not studied python, just learned some stuff by doing and googling, I wanna know why it is giving me a warning and what I should do differently.

Edit:
Tried with a boolean instead and still got the warning:

Short code that reproduces the warning for me:

```
import os
import glob

path = 'path'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as ins:
        do_once = False
        for line in ins:
            if "this" in line:
                print("this")
            elif "something_else" in line and do_once == False:
                do_once = True
```

Comment: I tried it and can't reproduce it. What PyCharm version are you using? Please post minimal **complete** code that, copied&pasted into a new PyCharm script, causes the problem.

Comment: Added minimal complete code that causes the warning, might be that I am using PyCharm 2016 v3.3, havn't had the time/reason to update yet but will try and check if that removes the warning.

Comment: Came here in 2023 with similar question. To summarize for clarity, basically the `do_once` variable here is declared initially in `do_once = False`. Later, in the `elif` the OP sets `do_once` to a new value at `do_once = True`. PyCharm is warning that the variable has been redeclared without usage. Why??? I'm using 2022.3.2 version. If I find an answer, I'll return...

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve the general case:

**What you may be doing**

```
v1 = []
for i in range(n):
    v1.append([randrange(10)])

v2 = []
for i in range(n):      # <<< Redeclared i without usage
    v2.append([randrange(10)])
```

**What you can do**

```
v1 = [[randrange(10)] for _ in range(5)]   # use dummy variable "_"
v2 = [[randrange(10)] for _ in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is PyCharm is being confused by the use of integers as flags, there are several alternatives that could be used in your use case.

Use a boolean flag instead of an integer

```
file_processed = False
for line in file:
    if 'this' in line and not file_processed:
        # do stuff
        file_processed = True
    ...
```

A better approach would be to jump simply stop once you have processed something in the file eg:

```
for filename in [...list...]:
    while open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'this_text' in line:
                # Do stuff
                break  # Break out of this for loop and go to the next file
```

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the warning?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, I tried this and I still get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but maybe an explanation:

Apparently, PyCharm is trying to avoid code like

```
do_once = False
do_once = True
```

However, it's also flagging *normal* code like the OP's:

```py
item_found = False
for item in items:
  if item == item_that_i_want:
    item_found = True

if item_found:
  # do something
```

or, something like

```py
last_message = ''
try:
  # do something
  if success:
    last_message = 'successfully did something'
  else:
    last_message = 'did something without success'

  # do something else
  if success:
    last_message = '2nd something was successful'
  else
    last_message = '2nd something was not successful'
  # and so on
  
  print(last_message)
```

*Redeclared 'last_message' defined above without usage* warning will appear for every line where `last_message` was reassigned without using it inbetween.

So, the workaround would be different for each case where this is happening:

1. ignore the warning(s)
2. print or log the value somewhere after setting it
3. perhaps make a function to call for setting/retrieving the value
4. determine if there's an alternate way to accomplish the desired outcome

My code was using the `last_message` example, and I just removed the code reassigning `last_message` in each case (though printing after each reassignment also removed the warnings). I was using it for testing to locate a problem, so it wasn't critical. Had I wanted to log the completed actions, I might've used a function to do so instead of reassigning the variable each time.

If I find a way to turn it off or avoid the warning in PyCharm, I'll update this answer.